# overflow:auto; flow out of div on chrome browser with tablet

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome

I have strange issue with chrome browser on android tablet.

I have used overflow:auto; property, it's flow out of div on android tablet.

this is pc screenshot on chrome:  http://screencast.com/t/71tAo8XINS

and here is android tablet screenshot on chrome : http://screencast.com/t/LYfzOI335Q

here is the test page : http://www.vizyonsoft.com/demo/mulakatik/test/test.html

this is my style of div

```
position:relative; height:560px; overflow-y:auto; border:1px solid #ddd; border-radius:3px; padding-top:10px;
```

How to I solve this. Please assist me.

Comment: I'm sorry; I'm a bit unsure what you are asking. Could you be more specific about what the intended functionality is as well as what specifically isn't working correctly?

Comment: What element are you referring to?? Please be more specific with the question.

Comment: my problem is child element still showing altough this is overflow as you can see the red rectangle in second screenshot. You can see the behavior diffirence first screenshot and second screenshot. first screenshot is mean working correctly but second isn't

Comment: Ohh. I see. Even with `overflow-y:auto;` the internal elements are showing up *on top* of the containing `div`. Very strange. This is beyond my skill to heal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need a scrolling div inside the div with the height set. Like this:

```
<div id="days" style="position:relative; height:560px; overflow-y: auto; border:1px solid #ddd; border-radius:3px; padding-top:10px;" class="col-md-7">

                            <div style="overflow:scroll">
```